# Conditional paste0 in R

Tags: r, dplyr

My dataframe looks like this:

```
N = 1000

a <- rnorm(N)
b <- rnorm(N)

df <- data.frame(a, b)
```

I would like to set up a conditional paste0 if the value of `a` is smaller than 10.

Specifically, I would like to print the value '0' (with no spaces) in front of the number in `a` if `a` < 10.

How can I do this? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You could do: `ifelse(a < 0, paste0("0", a), a)`

You might want to use `abs(a) < 10` or take special care of negative numbers in other ways.

Comment: You don't need the second paste0(a) since R will force the final result as a single str vector ;)

Answer (score 0):

I used @harre solution and implemented it in a more general function that take negative too.

For future questions please provide a smaller dataset, your's don't need 1000 lines dataframe.

```
a <- seq(-14, 14, by = 4)

text_number <- function(x){
  
  neg <- x < 0
  x <- abs(x)

  res <- ifelse(x < 10, paste0("0", x), x)
  res <- ifelse(neg, paste0("-", res), res)

  return(res)
}

text_number(a)
```